# Catch error messages globally for an iPhone (Objective C) application

Tags: iphone, exception, global

We use try, catch and finally to catch errors in iPhone and handle them in the controller. Can we create a global error handling code such that in case of any error, control passes to that method and we can handle all error related activities like sending message, showing alert etc from that code?

My idea is to have a single point for all error handling in Objective C (iPhone) apps.

In Coldfusion, we have an onError() method that is invoked if an error occur in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler()`:

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&handleException);
```

Then implement your handler as follows:

```
void handleException (NSException *exception)
{
   // exception handler code
}
```

Read [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html) for more information.

Comment: You probably meant to write a C method:

`void handleException (NSException *exception)`